# mule orchestration with rest

Tags: architecture, mule, saas

I am trying to do mule orchestration, I am following the document from mule here: [Mule docs](http://www.mulesoft.org/what-application-orchestration) under heading **Mule integration components**[image]

It works fine if there is a input data from Rest( I use rest instead of soap) call the http url which returns json data.

*Functionality of my http page is, authorize the user with credentials, if authenticated then upload data and give him back with some json data.*

Now, the problem here is login page is not displaying after rest/soap components. i.e json data from UI to the rest as post operation, then invoke the login page which is not happening. Rest/soap is used only for data transfer between the system, is there anyway handle my problem?. Is there anyway redirect to login page from a webservice calls?

I need to use REST because request is coming from one system to another and having input data as json format. But before uploading data in the vendor system(saas), user need to login always.

Comment: So you have in addition to your mule component a web app?

Comment: @ThomasRS, yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway redirect to login page from a webservice calls?

Have you tried returning an response with a 302 status code?

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302